# How do I cancel jobs/active operations in Datastore Admin?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I wanted to create a few entities to a new app from my existing python application.

Unfortunately, I realised that some of them are just too big and too expensive to copy this way (tens of millions of records). I cancelled the other apps' quotas and access rights, but the jobs are still there in the admin panel.

Will they expire one day? How do I cancel them?
(please notice that those are copy jobs, not backup jobs - backup jobs are easy to cancel)

[image: admin panel screenshot]

Comment: Check your application's Taskqueue. This Datastore Admin Copy jobs are running as a Task in Taskqueue. And you can delete those tasks from Appengine Admin Console.

Comment: And after deleting the tasks you can use Datastore Admin to actually clean them up by removing all _AE_* kinds.